# Delete missing datapoints (NA's) from multiple vectors

Tags: r, vector, statistics, missing-data

So I am working with biological data at a hospital, (I won't disclose anything here but I won't need to in order to ask this question).  We are looking at concentrations of antibodies taken a certain amount of time.  There are, for one reason or another, missing data points all over our data set.  **What I am doing is trying to remove the missing data points along with their corresponding time.**  Right now the basic goal is just to get some basic graphs and charts up and running but eventually we're going to want to create some logistical models and nonlinear dynamics models which we'll do in another language.

1) First I put my data into a vector along with it's corresponding time:

```
data <- read.csv("blablabla.csv" header = T)
Biomarker <- data[,2]
time <- data[,1]
```

2)Then I sort the data:

```
Biomarker <- Biomarker[order(time)]
time <- sort(time, decreasing = F)
```

3)Then I put the indexes of the NA values into a vector

```
NA_Index <- which(is.na(Biomarker))
```

4)Then I try to remove the data points at that index for both the biomarker and time vector

```
i <- 1
n <- length(NA_Index)

for(i:n){
    Biomarker[[NA_Index[i]]] <- NULL
    time[[NA_Index[i]]] <- NULL
}
```

Also I have tried a few different things than the one above:

1)

```
Biomarker <- Biomarker[-NA_Index[i]]
```

2)

```
Biomarker <- Biomarker[!= "NA"]
```

My question is: "How do I remove NA values from my vectors and remove the time with the same index?"

So Obviously I am very new to R and might be going about this in a completely wrong.  I just ask that you explain all what all the functions do if you post some code.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Would `complete.cases(data)` be more direct and accurate?

Comment: sorry I'm not sure what complete.cases() does

Comment: I think the [help page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/complete.cases.html) could probably use another example or two. Try: `x <- data.frame(a=c(1,NA,3),b=c(NA,22,33)); complete.cases(x); x[complete.cases(x),];`. You can always subset which columns of `x` are considered in scope for completeness, such as `x[complete.cases(x[,1]),]`.

Answer (score 1):

First I'd recommend storing your data in a `data.frame` instead of two vectors, since the entries in the vecotors correspond to cases this is a more appropriate datastructure.

```
my_table <- data.frame(time=time, Biomarker=Biomarker)
```

Then you can simply subset the whole `data.frame`, the first dimension are rows, the second columns, as usual, leave the second dimension free to keep all columns.

```
my_table <- my_table[!is.na(my_table$Biomarker), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> BioMarker
[1]  1  2 NA  3 NA  5
> is.na(BioMarker)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
> BioMarker[is.na(BioMarker)]
[1] NA NA
> BioMarker[! is.na(BioMarker)]
[1] 1 2 3 5
> BioMarker <- BioMarker[! is.na(BioMarker)]
> BioMarker
[1] 1 2 3 5
```